# Hibernate import.sql for Japanese data

Tags: hibernate, utf-8

When executing the insert query with Japanese value will work finely from MySQL workbench.
But when I tried it from my import.sql, the characters seems as "????" in database.

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>                    
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/import.sql</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>                    
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/import.sql</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
```

and use the url to connect as

```
<property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoConnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8" />
```